# Can not subscribe to a topic firebase notifications flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to push notifications to all users using FCM so I used topics for this , the problem is when I am trying to subscribe to a topic , I face this error

> Topic operation failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE. Will retry Topic operation.

using this function in initState

```
void subscribeToTopic() async {
    try {
      await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('Notifications');
      print('subscribed to topic');
    } catch (e) {
      print('error is $e');
    }
  }
```

Comment: It looks like the client is unable to reach the topic subscription service. If you're running this on a supported platform (iOS, Android) and it persists, it might be worth [reaching out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if there's a known outage.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I only face this problem when running app on the emulator